Beginner jQuery Math
I have a very beginner question about something I should know, but I am where I am :(
I understand the logic of what I want to do, but I lack the knowledge of how to write addition within the syntax of jQuery.
Can somebody, please show me how to write it?


    // This is not Code, this is me describing it in english
    // Creating the basic pattern
    string = #li-a
    string = #li-b
    string = #li-c
    // Is this correct? Should these be Strings?
    
    // Adding variable default values that will be modified
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
    var c = 3
    // Is this correct?
    
    // writing out how the pattern gets modified
    button-1 click adds .act to #li-a+0, #li-b+0, #li-c+0
    button-2 click adds .act to #li-a+1, #li-b+1, #li-c+1
    button-3 click adds .act to #li-a+2, #li-b+2, #li-c+2
    button-4 click adds .act to #li-a+0, #li-b+3, #li-c+1
    // I know how to write addClass but I don't know how to achieve the ''c+1'' etc part


Here's the template of what I'm trying to achieve:


$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button-1 a").click(function(e){
    // $("").addClass("act"); how can I write that li-c +1 math?
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#button-2 a").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#button-3 a").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#button-4 a").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
.page {margin:20px auto;max-width:300px;font-family:arial;}
ul {list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
a {text-decoration:none;color:#000;}
.list-wrap {margin-bottom:30px;}
.list {align-items:flex-start;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-between;}
.list a {display:block;padding:7px 15px;background:#eee;border-radius:5px;}
.list .act a {background:#ffb27a;}
.button-wrap {align-items:flex-start;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-between;}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="list-wrap">
    <ul class="list" id="list">
      <li class="list-item act" id="li-1"><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li class="list-item act" id="li-2"><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li class="list-item act" id="li-3"><a href="">3</a></li>
      <li class="list-item" id="li-4"><a href="">4</a></li>
      <li class="list-item" id="li-5"><a href="">5</a></li>
      <li class="list-item" id="li-6"><a href="">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <div class="button" id="button-1"><a href="">Button 1</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="button-2"><a href="">Button 2</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="button-3"><a href="">Button 3</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="button-4"><a href="">Button 4</a></div>
  </div>
</div>




jQuery ,addClass()

Yes, I know how to do addClass, what I don't know is how to achieve: ''#li-c+1'' where c is a pre-defined value.

This question is similar to: How can I build/concatenate strings in JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If that's what your problem is perhaps you should say that in your question.

That question might contain the answers I seek, but it is too difficult for me to understand. I edited my post to hopefully make it more clear what I am not understanding how to do.

What does this have to do with math? The jQuery library doesn't have any mathematical functions. That's all just basic JavaScript.

You can use '#li-c-' + (c+1) to form the selector string.

I mentioned jQuery, because I need the syntax of jQuery. “Math” part is the addition to ID numbers. And “beginner”, because my current knowledge is insufficient to figure out on my own :) I’m learning and it helps a lot if someone can give me pointers. How would you write that '#li-c-' + (c+1) in script?

You can use a template literal to substitute a+N, b+N, and c+N into the selector strings.


$(document).ready(function() {
  let a = 0;
  let b = 1;
  let c = 2;

  function addClasses(increment) {
    $(".list-item").removeClass("act"); // Remove from other items
    $(`#li-${a+increment}, #li-${b+increment}, #li-${c+increment}`).addClass("act"); // Add to these items
  }

  $("#button-1 a").click(function(e) {
    addClasses(1);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#button-2 a").click(function(e) {
    addClasses(2);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#button-3 a").click(function(e) {
    addClasses(3);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#button-4 a").click(function(e) {
    addClasses(4);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
.page {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-family: arial;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.list-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.list {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.list .act a {
  background: #ffb27a;
}

.button-wrap {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="list-wrap">
    <ul class="list" id="list">
      <li class="list-item act" id="li-1"><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li class="list-item act" id="li-2"><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li class="list-item act" id="li-3"><a href="">3</a></li>
      <li class="list-item" id="li-4"><a href="">4</a></li>
      <li class="list-item" id="li-5"><a href="">5</a></li>
      <li class="list-item" id="li-6"><a href="">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <div class="button" id="button-1"><a href="">Button 1</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="button-2"><a href="">Button 2</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="button-3"><a href="">Button 3</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="button-4"><a href="">Button 4</a></div>
  </div>
</div>




You need preventDefault on the numbered links too. And why not delegate?

Thank you for writing this snippet! It does work as I wanted. Just one thing - what if I want a completely different pattern for button-4? For example: a+0, b+2, c+3.

Then you would have to write specific code in that event listener instead of using the general function that applies the same pattern to all.
